# Regex match word that doesn't end by something

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the following string :

`abcdef abcdcd abcdab`

I want to match all the words that begin by  `abcd` but not the one that ends by cd. On Regex101.com, I tried :

```
\babcd(?=^cd)
```

and also

```
\babcd(?=!cd)
```

but no hit. This is the "(?=**not** cd)" that block me.

Note that I don't want to match `ef` or `ab` at the end of the two others words, only `abcd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\babcd(?!\w*cd\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UOyOwa/3)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `abcd` - a literal `abcd` substring
- `(?!\w*cd\b)` - a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`) that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are any 0+ word chars followed with `cd` and a word boundary (end of word)).

Replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]` or `\p{L}` / `\p{Alpha}` (if supported) to only match letters.